# Laravel Passport view

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

I need to change the template for passport /oauth/authorize. This template is located in /vendor/laravel/passport/resources/views/authorize.blade.php. How to extend this template, and change html/css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#requesting-tokens) views: 
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-views` 
So, The authorized.blade.php will be in `resources/views/vendor/passport` and you can extend or change it.